# How to combine two values in 1 variable in r?

Tags: r

I have this variable 'country'

df

```
id age  country 
1  21   Denmark 
2  20   Sweden  
3  20   Sweden  
4  21   NA   
5  22   Other
```

This is what I want

```
df
id age  country new
1  21   Denmark  1
2  20   Sweden   2
3  20   Sweden   2
4  21   NA       0
5  22   Other    0
```

I want Denmark to be coded as 1 and Sweden as 2 and NA + Other as 0. How do I do this in r?

Comment: Please try to share reproducible example and expected output. Not sure about structure of you dataframe, but see if this works: df$Country_code <- ifelse(df$Country == 'Denmark', 1, ifelse(df$Country == 'Sweden', 2, 0))

Comment: I tried, but this is my first time, so I don't know how to post the df correctly. Your code worked, but NA is not marked as 0, still NA.

Comment: You can use dput(df).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~d, ~age, ~country, 
  1, 21, "Denmark", 
  2, 20, "Sweden",  
  3, 20, "Sweden",  
  4, 21, NA,
  5, 22, "Other")
df <- df %>% mutate(new = case_when(
  country == "Sweden" ~2, 
  country == "Denmark" ~ 1, 
  TRUE ~ 0))
  
df
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#      d   age country   new
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1     1    21 Denmark     1
# 2     2    20 Sweden      2
# 3     3    20 Sweden      2
# 4     4    21 NA          0
# 5     5    22 Other       0
```

Comment: Thanks! But, NA is still NA:(

Comment: @Quinn Not sure why, it worked in my code.  Can you edit your question to add in what you tried and the result?

Comment: I'm sorry, I typed in wrong. It worked!:) Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be an approach with datatable:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df <- setDT(df)

df <- df[,`:=`(
  new = case_when(
    country == "Sweden" ~1, 
    country == "Denmark" ~ 2, 
    TRUE ~ 0)
)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `base` R way:

```
corr <- data.frame(country = c("Denmark", "Sweden", NA_character_, "Other"),
                   new = c(1, 2, 0, 0))

merge(df, corr, by = "country")
```

The output:

```
> merge(df, corr, by = "country")
  country id age new
1 Denmark  1  21   1
2   Other  5  22   0
3  Sweden  2  20   2
4  Sweden  3  20   2
5    <NA>  4  21   0
```

The data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:5, age = c(21L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 22L), country = c("Denmark", 
                                                                             "Sweden", "Sweden", NA, "Other")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                    -5L))
```